# Using QgsMapCanvasTracer/QgsTracer in custom tool

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, trace

I've made a custom tool for digitizing polygons in qgis, similar to build in Add Feature tool but with some modifications. I need to integrate tracing into that tool also, but I haven't figured out how.

I know that in the API, there are QgsMapCanvasTracer class and QgsTracer class, but I don't know how to use them in my custom tool.

Can someone give me some hints or examples regarding this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I would refer the documentation and code provided [QgsMapCanvas Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a2a91ee382ce605e3382b74693f9c4d80), [qgsmapcanvastracer.cpp](https://qgis.org/api/qgsmapcanvastracer_8cpp_source.html respectively

> ```
>   : mCanvas( canvas )   
>   35   , mMessageBar( messageBar )   
>   36    
>   37 {   
>   38   sTracers.insert( canvas, this );   
>   39    
>   40   // when things change we just invalidate the graph - and set up new  
>   parameters again only when necessary   
>   41   connect( canvas, &QgsMapCanvas::destinationCrsChanged, this,  
>  &QgsMapCanvasTracer::invalidateGraph );   
>   42   connect( canvas, &QgsMapCanvas::layersChanged, this,  
>  &QgsMapCanvasTracer::invalidateGraph );    
>   43   connect( canvas, &QgsMapCanvas::extentsChanged, this,  
>  &QgsMapCanvasTracer::invalidateGraph );   
>   44   connect( canvas, &QgsMapCanvas::currentLayerChanged, this,  
>  &QgsMapCanvasTracer::onCurrentLayerChanged );   
>   45   connect( canvas->snappingUtils(), &QgsSnappingUtils::configChanged,  
>  this, &QgsMapCanvasTracer::invalidateGraph );
> ```